# Unable to destroy Activity (service is not registered)

Tags: android, service, android-activity

****EDIT SOLVED BY DOING THIS:****
I have solved it by changing my `onDestroy()` of my Activity and the `ServiceConnection::onServiceDisconnected()`.

I have added a boolean to check if I'm bounded to the Service called `boundToService`.
The ServiceConnection:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        myService = ((EventService.MyBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(getPackageName(), "ServiceConnection::onServiceDisconnected() called");
        boundToService = false;
    }
};
```

And the `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(getPackageName(), "Destroying Activity");
    if (boundToService && mConnection != null) {
        doUnbindService();
    }
}
```

This is how the binding and unbinding is done in the activity:

```
public void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, EventService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    boundToService = true;
}

public void doUnbindService() {
    unbindService(mConnection);
    boundToService = false;
}
```

As Guillaume said, calling `super.onDestroy()` first is a must.

****END OF SOLVE****

I have a `Foreground Service` that polls GPS data, and the `MapActivity` requests that data every 3 seconds. When the `onDestroy()` of the `MapActivity` is called, I get this LogCat error:

```
06-11 21:26:35.591: D/CLIPBOARD(14801): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-11 21:26:44.451: D/dalvikvm(14801): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1371 entries
06-11 21:26:44.451: D/AndroidRuntime(14801): Shutting down VM
06-11 21:26:44.456: W/dalvikvm(14801): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4b1f8)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.project4.mtl/com.project4.mtl.EventActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.project4.mtl.EventActivity$1@416179d8
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3142)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1192)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.project4.mtl.EventActivity$1@416179d8
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:888)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1211)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:375)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at com.project4.mtl.EventActivity.onDestroy(EventActivity.java:175)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1082)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3111)
06-11 21:26:44.476: E/AndroidRuntime(14801):    ... 11 more`
```

And of course the code around line 175 where the exception is caused in my program:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If you want more code snippets, just tell me.

****edit****

This is the code for the ServiceConnection:

```
public void doBindService() {
    //ComponentName service = startService(new Intent(this,
        //  EventService.class));
    bindService(new Intent(this, EventService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

`mConnection` is type of ServiceConnection:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        myService = ((EventService.MyBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that the service is destroyed before the activity is destroyed?

Comment: The service does get destroyed first.

Comment: That's the core problem then. How is it getting destroyed?

Comment: @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.e(getPackageName(), "Destroying Service");
  super.onDestroy();
  locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  if(notificationManager!=null){
   notificationManager.cancelAll();
  }
  stopForeground(true);
 }

Comment: I think the first thing you have to do in the function is `super.onDestroy();`, before unbind the service.

Comment: Guillaume, I did that but it's still the same.

Comment: I think you need to do something on ServiceConnection::onServiceDisconnected. I would need to see more code to figure out exactly what, but that's a good starting point for you.

Comment: Solved it guys. It's in the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That's worked for me ! Just call the function unbindService() from getApplicationContext() instead of "this" context. (same for binding the service)

```
getApplicationContext().unbindService(mServiceConnection);
```

Comment: Is it really unbinding when you call it from `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: I have the same issue with application context.

Answer (score 3):

You could just set `mService` to null in `onServiceDisconnected` and check for that in `onDestroy`. Like this:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            mService = ((LoadArticlesService.LoadArticlesBinder) binder).getService();
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;
        }
    };
```

onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }
}
```

Works fine.

Comment: Why would you set service to null?